# response.success is not a function

Tags: parse-platform

My client code sends a placeID to be search in a Parse class called "POIS". If no entry exist for placeID, I make a web query and return the results. The cloud code I have is below. The error thrown is response.success is not a function

```
Parse.Cloud.define("returnValues", function(request, response) {
  var placeId = request.params.placeId;
  var query = new Parse.Query("POIS");
  query.equalTo("placeId", placeId);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      if(results.length == 0) {
        // Nothing Exist for this placeId
        var urlReq = "https://a.b.c.d/retunplaceDetails/search?q=" + placeId";
        var request = require('request');
        request(urlReq, function (error, rresponse, body) {
        if (!error && rresponse.statusCode == 200) {
          var res = JSON.parse(body);
          var pois = res['data'];
          console.log(pois); <======= THIS PRINTS the OUTPUT from WebService
          response.success(pois); <====== THIS generates the error
        } // valid HTTP Response
        else {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }); // request
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Results returned failed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: There are two response variables, one provided by the cloud function and the other provided by the request function. Try changing the name of either one of them.

Comment: I changed it and updated my question. Still no luck.